# Child component loses parent table formatting

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently I have a bootstrap table that displays a list of results. I have a button that when pressed I want a new row to appear with inputs at the bottom of the current table. The issue I am having is that the html in my child component doesn't retain the formatting of my parent component's bootstrap table (all three of the `<td>` rows are crammed into one column on the parent table). Below is my parent component. The child component selector is `<app-addBin>`. Does anyone know how to get a child component to retain the formatting of the parent compoent's table?

```
 <table class = 'table'> 
            <thead><!--Start of affected code-->
                <tr>
                    <th>Bin ID</th>
                    <th>Exclude MRB Xfer</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                 <tr *ngFor= 'let value of values' >
                    <td class="binId" align="align-left" >{{value.binId}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name='excludeMrbxfer' 
                        [(ngModel)] = "values.excludeMrbxfer" (click)='toggleChange(value)'>
                        {{value.excludeMrbxfer | yesNo}}</button>   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name='status' 
                        [(ngModel)] = "values.status" (click)='toggleChangeStatus(value)'>
                        {{value.status | status}}</button> 
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr *ngIf="isFoo"><app-addBin></app-addBin><tr>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name='status' (click)="isFoo =!isFoo"
                        >{{isFoo ? 'Cancel' : 'New'}}</button>   
                    </tr>
```

Here is the html from my child component

```
                     <td>
                         <select >
                            <option *ngFor='let value of values' [value]='values.binId'>{{value.binId}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name='excludeMrbxfer' 
                        [(ngModel)] = "newBin.excludeMrbxfer" (click)='toggleChange(newBin)'>
                        {{newBin.excludeMrbxfer | yesNo}}</button> </td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name='status' 
                        [(ngModel)] = "newBin.status" (click)='toggleChangeStatus(newBin)'>
                        {{newBin.status | status}}</button> </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that when trying to add an Angular component to a `<tr>` element the compiler looks for a `<td>` element so placing a selector inside the `<tr>` tag like so `<tr><app-addBin></app-addBin</td>` will not result in the component rendering inside the table as a `<td>` but will cram the entire component html template inside one column. By adding an attribute selector (I think that's what this is called) to the component i.e. `selector: 'app-addbin, [app-addbin]',`  you can add the selector directly to the `<td>` element like so `<td app-addBin></td>` and now the `<td>` elements inside the component html template will render correctly inside the table.

Comment: :i tried ur solutionbut in my case child component data not rendrer?